# php and mysql multiple and/or in select statement

Tags: php, mysql, logical-operators

I have noticed that running a select where you have multiple ANDs on the same column does not work, for example: select * from x where y = 1 AND y = 2;

In my design I have a situation where my plan (and am open to better designs) was to build a sql statement based on the User's input.

So in my code we have an ID, this ID must have item1 and item 2. They can also have items 3 through to 10, and can choose whether they are in an AND/OR logic.

For example:

`select id from designers where item = :item1 AND item = :item2 OR item = :item3;`

The expectation from aboe is that the User gets an id with item1 and either or both item2 and 3. Now I can build the above as a string no problem, but if this type of statement is not going to work what would be the best approach?

Do I get all of the items and then process them in php using logical operators instead of through a sql statement? With this I could drop the need to build and store query strings in the DB. I hope there is an efficient method akin to what I have above with a sql statement..

Thanks

G

Comment: how can y be 2 things? its either 1 or 2?

Comment: Select ... from ... where ... in(....) group by .... having count(*) = [number of items in IN()] - or some variant thereof.